# Oozie xmlns version

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, oozie

I have started learning Oozie recently.

I have confusion on versioning of xmlns in Oozie actions. If I have Oozie **4.2.0** installed then can I use only the versions of xmlns declared in 4.2.0 documentation like for hive here(https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_HiveActionExtension.html#Hive_Action)

or can I use the latest xmlns versions also (http://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.0.0/DG_HiveActionExtension.html#Hive_Action).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 4.2.0 xmlns versions with oozie 4.2.0. 
It's possible to add newer schemas with properties like oozie.service.SchemaService.wf.ext.schemas, oozie.service.SchemaService.coord.ext.schemas and oozie.service.SchemaService.bundle.ext.schemas, but you have to be aware that the parsing code part might be missing for the newer properties allowed in the new schemas.